# How to use jQuery Datatables on VB.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to integrate jQuery Datatables to an ASP.NET project, I already searched for some help of how to fill this datatables by using an aspx method. This is what I have without success.

```
<table id="usertables" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>UserId</th>
         <th>UserName</th>
         <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my table on my html file that has just a header with 3 columns and tbody is not set yet. After this I use this code to fill it

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "crud_location/fill_users.aspx/BindDatatable",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#usertables").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].UserId + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].UserName + "</td><td>Some location data</td></tr>");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
       });
```

Then I try to render jQuery Datatable running this script.

```
            $('#usertables').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true
            } );
```

But when I run all this processes they throw me the table like this...

[jQuery Datatable Result](http://s30.postimg.org/x3es81p9t/Screenshot_1.png)

The first row says "No data available in table", this make me think that the table got render before all records are appended to the table, and if I type any char on Search field, everything disappear, only "No data available in table" is there and no records are showed.

Where can I find an specific example of how to use this datatables on VB.NET? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your plugin like this:

```
idTable = $("#my-table").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "path/to/ServerSideProcessor"
        });
```

And you will need a Server Side Processor returning your data for each datatables parameters send each time you do a search, sort, etc. You don't need to program the server side as there are different codes already working.

Here is an example for asp.net in C# with a mysql server:
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6678/serverside-processing-for-asp-net-c-with-sql-server/p1

More information here:
http://datatables.net/development/server-side/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the datatable call before the close of success function inside ajax function, like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "crud_location/fill_users.aspx/BindDatatable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#usertables").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].UserId + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].UserName + "</td><td>Some location data</td></tr>");
            }
             //HERE I CALL THE LOADDATATABLE FUNCTION
             loaddatatable();

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
   });

   function loaddatatable() {
      $('#usertables').DataTable();
    }
```